# Using jQuery with google places autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

Hello guys I'm using google places autocomplete for `establishments` in Russia. I'm having problems with manipulating DOM elements.

What I'm trying to achieve:
In HTML I have div with `autocompleteString` class which is hidden with `CSS`. In function `fillIn` I'm adding `HTML` to it from google response with `place.adr_address`. Then I'm using class `locality` from that response to populate `input` with class name `cityRu`. Not this part works fine.

Problem is that I will have multiple `accommodationDivs` that will be added dynamically and I'm trying to add `$('.autocompleteString').html(place.adr_address)` and `$('.cityRu').val(cityRu)` to each one of them. I'm trying to target classes `autocompleteString` and `cityRu` closest to my autocomplete input.
I'm trying to achieve something like this:
`$('.yourAccomm').closest('.accommodationDivs').find('.cityRu').val('mytext')` but instead of `$('.yourAccomm')` I need to have something like JQ `$(this)` or vanilla JS equivalent, but everything I've tried so far didn't work. Can anyone please help me with this ?

This is example of `place.adr_address` response:
`<span class="street-address">ул. Рубинштейна, 20</span>, <span class="locality">Санкт-Петербург</span>, <span class="country-name">Россия</span>, <span class="postal-code">191002</span>`

JS:

```
function searchHotels() {
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.yourAccomm');

    var options = {
        types: ['establishment'],
        componentRestrictions: {country: 'ru'}
    };

    var autocompletes = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputs[i], options);
        autocomplete.inputId = inputs[i].id;
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillIn);
        autocompletes.push(autocomplete);
    }

    function fillIn() {
        var place = this.getPlace();
        console.log(this)

        // console.log(inputs[0])

        // inputs[0].style.background = "red";

        $('.autocompleteString').html(place.adr_address);
        var cityRu = $('.locality').text();
        console.log(cityRu)
        $('.cityRu').val(cityRu);
    }
}
searchHotels();
```

HTML:

```
<div class="accommodationDivs first_accommodation">
    <div class="steps__f-grp form-group">
        <label><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>Name of hotel / hostel (first entry)</label>
        <div class="steps__f-grp__accomo input-group">
            <input type="text" class="input--margin-r form-control yourAccomm" aria-label="Name of accommodation" name="first_accommodation" tabindex="11" placeholder="Enter a location">

            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button id='add_field_button_1' class="steps__f-grp__btn-more btn btn-secondary" type="button">+</button>
            </span>
        </div>
        <label for="first_accommodation" generated="true" class="error"></label>
    </div>

    <div class="autocompleteString">

    </div>

    <div class="steps__f-grp form-group">
        <label for="cityRu">City</label>
        <input id="cityRu" class="form-control cityRu" type="text" name="cityRu" tabindex="12">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm bothered by the for loop. Do you have multiple address inputs ?

Comment: @Kulvar At start I have one but user has option for adding more of them. Autocomplete works fine with multiple inputs for autocomplete with `for loop`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I managed to solve this. Logic is a bit messy and hacky but it gets the job done.
First we get ID of input that user is typing for autocomplete. Then we add data attribute `city` to that with input and we give value to that data attribute with city we get from google API. Then we use that data attribute to populate nearest input with city name.

```
// Google places API code
function searchHotels() {

    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.yourAccomm');
    var cityRu;

    var options = {
        types: ['establishment'],
        componentRestrictions: {country: 'ru'},
    };

    var autocompletes = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputs[i], options);
        autocomplete.inputId = inputs[i].id;
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillIn);
        autocompletes.push(autocomplete);
    }

    function fillIn() {
        var place = this.getPlace();
        var myInput = $('#' + this.inputId);

        myInput.attr('data-city', place.address_components[3].long_name);

        myInput.on('datachange', function(){
            var localityData = myInput.data("city");
            myInput.closest('.accommodationDivs').find('.cityRu').val(localityData);
        });

        myInput.data('city', place.address_components[3].long_name).trigger('datachange');

    }

}
searchHotels();
```