# Show google places autocomplete as according to the selected dropdown city

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to show the google places as according to the selected dropdown city

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

```
<select id="city" name="property_city" class="form-control" required>
    <option value="" selected>Select City</option>
    <option value="Islamabad">Islamabad</option>
    <option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
</select>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDtqlHZRaMYSW-Y9JlriCG-R7jEugHsPjo&v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>

<script>
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('query');
var options = { 
types: ['(regions)'], 
componentRestrictions: {country: 'pk'} 
};
var autocompletes = [];
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputs[i], options);
autocomplete.inputId = inputs[i].id;
autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillIn); 
autocompletes.push(autocomplete);
} 
function fillIn() {
console.log(this.inputId);
var place = this.getPlace();
console.log(place. address_components[0].long_name);
}
</script>
```

I want to show the google places as according to the selected dropdown city

Comment: Does any of this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153720/using-jquery-with-google-places-autocomplete

Comment: Ok. Can you figure this out to display the google places according to the selected city.

Comment: Could you please help me out with this problem

Comment: I tried your code and getting this error.
"Google Maps JavaScript API warning: SensorNotRequired https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required"

Comment: @RazaBarlas You have to add output what you get From API then I can help you.